# How to retrieve mysql data using volley with java in android without php?

Tags: android, mysql, performance, android-volley

How to retrieve MySql data using Volley with Java in Android without PHP?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You can use Java on the server as well.

Comment: Removed unnecessary comments, reduced question marks and added some capitals

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with the Server you have to write API in java. Which will include database name, username, password to access, sql query to fetch data.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DB_URL,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // responce may be String, JSONOnject, JSONArray. Handle with your own actions.
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Error occurs in API(loop,TimeOutError,...)
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError  {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                // Map your Key and Value to match in the API to perform actions.
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```